# I'm trying to identify the number of student entered in do-while , and display the number out-side the loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, do-while

I created the program that takes an input from the user,and display the number of student have been entered..

I use do-while loop because at the end of the program will ask the use "will you want to continue ?" if the user put y, it will loop again to get the input as well. I tried to make an array for it, but it didn't work well for displaying the number of student and the average grade as well...

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    int student_id, test1,test2, final_mark;
    float total_up;
    char answer;


    do {

        printf("\nProgram to Calculate Student Grade\n");
        printf("Insert the student ID: ");
        scanf("%d",&student_id);
        printf("\nInsert marks for Test 1 (total of 25 ): ");
        scanf(" %d",&test1);
        if (test1 >25)
        {
            printf("The marks is greater than 25.Please re-insert it again.");
            printf("\nInsert marks for Test 1 (total of 25 ): ");
            scanf(" %d",&test1);
        }
           printf("\nInsert marks for Test 2 (total of 25 ): ");
           scanf(" %d",&test2);
           if (test2 >25)
        {
            printf("The marks is greater than 25.Please re-insert it again.");
            printf("\nInsert marks for Test 2 (total of 25 ): ");
            scanf(" %d",&test2);
        }
            printf("\nInsert marks for Final Exam: (total of 50): ");
            scanf(" %d",&final_mark);
            if ( final_mark > 50 )
            {
                printf("\nThe Final Exam is greater than 50. Please re-insert it again.");
                printf("\nInsert marks for Final Exam: (total of 50) ");
                scanf("%d",&final_mark);
            }

        total_up = test1 + test2 + final_mark;
        printf("Total Marks: %.2f",total_up);
        if (total_up >=80)
        {
            printf("\nGrade is A\n");
        }
        else if (total_up >=60)
        {
            printf("\nGrade is B\n");
        }
        else if (total_up >=50)
        {
            printf("\nGrade is C\n");
        }
        else if (total_up >=40)
        {
            printf("\nGrade is D\n");
        }
        else if (total_up <40)
        {
            printf("\nGrade is F\n");
        }

        printf("Do you want to continue? ");
        scanf(" %c",&answer);
    }while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

        printf("\nTotal number of students entered is %d ", student_id);
        total_up = total_up / 2;
        printf("\nTotal number of students entered is %.2f ",total_up);
    return 0;
}
```

let say the input will be :

```
Program to Calculate Student Grade 
Insert the student ID : 123 
Insert marks for Test 1 ( total of 25 ): 15
Insert marks for Test 2 ( total of 25 ): 20

Insert marks for Final Exam ( total of 50 ): 42

Total Marks : 77.00 
Grade is B 

Do you want to continue ? y 

Program to Calculate Student Grade 
Insert the student ID : 456
Insert marks for Test 1 ( total of 25 ): 21
Insert marks for Test 2 ( total of 25 ): 23

Insert marks for Final Exam ( total of 50 ): 47

Total Marks : 91.00 
Grade is A 

Do you want to continue ? n
```

So, after the do-while terminates.. 
What I expect is

```
Total number of students entered is 2
Total number of students entered is 84.00 

Average grade is A
```

I tried an array for student and the test, but it didn't work probably.. 
Any Idea about it?

Comment: You don't count the number of students "added", instead you print the last `student_id`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , you mean by using for loop for students  and the marks as well ?

Comment: You should add a new variable like `student_count` which you initialize to zero, and in the existing loop you increase it by one. Then after the loop it will be equal to the number of students added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For counting student and calculating subtotal, take two extra variables and initialize them to 0 outside the loop. Then, inside the loop, increment the student_count with each iteration of the loop and also add the total marks of current student with the variable of calculating subtotal. Finally, it is easy to calculate average. Just divide subtotal by the student count.

Also, for calculating grade, you can keep it inside another function, as you have to do it twice, once inside the loop and again outside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void showGrade(float marks)
{
    if (marks >= 80) {
        printf("Grade is A\n");
    }
    else if (marks >= 60) {
        printf("Grade is B\n");
    }
    else if (marks >= 50) {
        printf("Grade is C\n");
    }
    else if (marks >= 40) {
        printf("Grade is D\n");
    }
    else if (marks < 40) {
        printf("Grade is F\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int student_id, test1, test2, final_mark, student_count = 0;
    float total_up, grand_total = 0, average;
    char answer;
    do {
        student_count++;
        printf("\nProgram to Calculate Student Grade\n");
        printf("Insert the student ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &student_id);
        printf("\nInsert marks for Test 1 (total of 25 ): ");
        scanf(" %d", &test1);
        if (test1 > 25) {
            printf("The marks is greater than 25. Please insert it again.");
            printf("\nInsert marks for Test 1 (total of 25): ");
            scanf(" %d", &test1);
        }
        printf("Insert marks for Test 2 (total of 25 ): ");
        scanf(" %d",&test2);
        if (test2 > 25) {
            printf("The marks is greater than 25. Please insert it again.");
            printf("\nInsert marks for Test 2 (total of 25): ");
            scanf(" %d", &test2);
        }
        printf("Insert marks for Final Exam: (total of 50): ");
        scanf(" %d", &final_mark);
        if (final_mark > 50) {
            printf("\nThe Final Exam is greater than 50. Please insert it again.");
            printf("\nInsert marks for Final Exam: (total of 50): ");
            scanf("%d", &final_mark);
        }
        total_up = test1 + test2 + final_mark;
        grand_total += total_up;
        printf("\nTotal Marks: %.2f\n", total_up);
        showGrade(total_up);
        printf("\nDo you want to continue? ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
    } while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
    printf("\nTotal number of students entered is %d ", student_count);
    average = grand_total / student_count;
    printf("\nAverage total number of students entered is %.2f\n", average);
    printf("\nAverage ");
    showGrade(average);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize one variable to 0, for storing count of total number of student and increment it after accepting all data from user. At the end just print that variable as "Total number of students entered".`

```
int studentCount=0, studentTotal=0;
do {
// code to accept all data
studentTotal = studentTotal + total_up;
studentCount++;
}while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

printf("\n Total number of students entered is %d ", studentCount);
float studentAverage = studentTotal / studentCount;
 if (studentAverage >=80)
    {
        printf("\n Average grade is A\n");
    }
    else if (studentAverage >=60)
    {
        printf("\n Average grade is B\n");
    }
    else if (studentAverage >=50)
    {
        printf("\n Average grade is C\n");
    }
    else if (studentAverage >=40)
    {
        printf("\n Average grade is D\n");
    }
    else if (studentAverage <40)
    {
        printf("\n Average grade is F\n");
    }
```

Comment: What about the average mark based on the input, going to be 77+91=168,168/2=84. will divided by two based on the how many marks have been input.

Comment: I suggest that you should make a function for calculating grade and call it whenever you want to use

Comment: sorry for the mistake I edited my answer, please see it